# Exclude folder from htpasswd

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I need to password protect a website with a username/password but need to keep the "/assets" folder accessible as files like images/css are being embedded on other sites.

I have this for the protection:

```
Order Allow,Deny
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy Any
```

How can I specify to protect everything bar the /assets folder?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'd use, in a `.htaccess` file in the `assets/` directory:

```
Satisfy Any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

See the examples here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require

Comment: Ah I was stuck in a single .htaccess mindset. This worked perfectly. Thank you!